# LinkedIn API Doesn't Support All Characters?

Tags: xml, api, linkedin-api

I want to create a share with the LinkedIn API, but it won't allow me to use < or > for obvious reasons.  Since they use XML it's quite tricky.  I've tried url encoding, backslash insertion, and even HTML character replacement for < > like gt; and lt;

```
var body = "\
    <share>\
      <comment>" + message + " </comment>\
      <visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility>\
    </share>\
  ";
```

How can I include a < or > without having the LinkedIn server freak out when it sees the "unexpected character"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to construct XML by concatenating strings together is always going to be error-prone. You've not said in the question what programming language you're using, but any modern language should have libraries to build XML properly and handle all the necessary escaping for you.

Alternatively [this document](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/api-requests-json) suggests that the LinkedIn APIs can work with JSON as well as with XML, which may be an easier approach particularly if you're working in a language like JavaScript.